# Grep command to extract a kubernetes pod name

Tags: bash, kubernetes, grep

I am currently working on a `bash` script to reduce the time it takes for me to build the `db` for a project. 
Currently I have several databases running in the same namespace and I want to extract only the specific pod name.

I run `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elastic                     1/1     Running   0          37h
mysql                       1/1     Running   0          37h
```

Now I want to save one of the pod names.

I'm currently running this `foo=$(kubectl get pods | grep -e "mysql")`
and it returns `mysql                  1/1     Running   0          37h` which is the expected results of the command. Now I just want to be able to extract the pod name as that variable so that I can pass it on at a later time.

Comment: Use `foo=$(kubectl get pods | awk '$1 ~ /mysql/{print $1}'`

Comment: I don't get it. You want to extract `mysql` from the output? And you do it by grepping `mysql`?

Comment: I bet there could be `mysql-deployment-xxxxx-yyyy` structure

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you

```
foo=$(kubectl get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep -e "mysql")
```

Answer (score 6):

`kubectl` already allows you to extract only the names:

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items..metadata}{.name}{"\n"}{end}' | fgrep mysql
```

Comment: what does the double dot do in the above? what does it mean? or is it a typo?

Comment: @2bon2b `..` is _nested descendants_. See [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/) or [this](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you merely needs to get only pod names to reuse these later.

The `kubectl get --help` provides a lot of good information on what you can achieve with just a `kubectl` without invoking the rest of the heavy artillery like `awk`, `sed`, etc.

> List a single pod in JSON output format.
>
> `kubectl get -o json pod web-pod-13je7`
>
> List resource information in custom columns.
>
> `kubectl get pod test-pod -o
>   custom-columns=CONTAINER:.spec.containers[0].name,IMAGE:.spec.containers[0].image`
>
> Return only the phase value of the specified pod.
>   `kubectl get -o template pod/web-pod-13je7 --template={{.status.phase}}`

In this particular case I see at least 2 workarounds :

1)  Custom columns. You can get virtually any output (and then you can `grep`/`tr`/`awk` if needed):

```
$ kubectl get pods --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=NAME_OF_MY_POD:.metadata.name

mmmysql-6fff9ffdbb-58x4b
mmmysql-6fff9ffdbb-72fj8
mmmysql-6fff9ffdbb-p76hx
mysql-tier2-86dbb787d9-r98qw
nginx-65f88748fd-s8mgc
```

2) jsonpath (the one @vault provided):

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items..metadata.name}'
```

Hope that sheds light on options you have to choose from. 
Let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get pods | grep YOUR_POD_STARTING_NAME
```

For Example

```
kubectl get pods | grep mysql
```